# C# button click and unclick actions

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a button(named: open port) when it clicked the following code executed:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
   try
   {
      if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
      {    
          serialPort1.Open();                         
      }
      else
      {
         MessageBox.Show("Port is Open by other party!");    
      }   
   }
   catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
   {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
   }
}
```

what I want to do is :

1. The button keep clicked and its name changes to (close port)
2. I press it and I want it to perform the following code:

   ```
   serialPort1.Close();
   Form1 myForm = new Form1();
   this.Close();
   ```

can you help me?

Comment: is this in WPF or Win Forms or something else?

Comment: Why do you need to create a new form? What is wrong with the one that is already open?

Comment: You can add a finally onto your try/catch, is there a problem with adding action(2) to the try statement after the if/else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want a button that toggles opening and closing the port then it should be sufficient to just do the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)     
{
  try
  {
    if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {    
      serialPort1.Open();
      this.button1.Text = "Close Port";                   
    }
    else
    {
      serialPort1.Close();
      this.button1.Text = "Open Port";  
    }   
  }
  catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
  }
}
```

As for the extra code:

```
Form1 myForm = new Form1();
this.Close();
```

This new instance of `Form1` would be disposed once it is out of scope, and closing `this` form means you no longer have any UI.

Comment: thank you very much, I'm now one step to finish my project, I want to open windows explorer and chose a text then put it in textbox, which worked nice for me, but If I didn't chose a file it shows my an error (empty path name is not legal) what should I do to solve this problem ?

                    OpenFileDialog of = new OpenFileDialog();

                    of.ShowDialog();

                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(of.FileName);

                    richTextBox1.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();

Comment: Just as the error says, the path name cannot be empty.  Make sure `of.FileName` is set, or some other path property.  Also, don't forget if an answer helped solved your question, you should click the *Accept* checkmark beneath the up/down-vote arrows.

Comment: thanks man, I'm aware of the problem, I will demonstrate this to my instructor " as you can see, we either copy/paste the input, or if we store as text we can access it directly"" so if I opened the windows explorer and I DID'NT chose any file, I want a messagebox to be shown rather than program stopping debug, how I can write that?
@OhBeWise 
I'm sorry to bother you, but I cant ask any question for the next 7 days :)

Comment: If I understand what you're wanting, it sounds like you just need to check the file name before attempting to open it.  If the string file name is empty (or doesn't exist or whatever other parameter you have) then show your message box, else open the file.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing you'll get to a toggle button in winform is using a ToolStripButton that you have to add to a ToolStrip.

Set the ToolStripButton.CheckOnClick to true and then code the ToolStripButton.CheckStateChangedEvent.

```
private void toolStripButton1_CheckStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Checked means it's clicked
    if (toolStripButton1.Checked)
    {
        if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
        {
            serialPort1.Open();
            toolStripButton1.Text = "Close Port";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (serialPort1.IsOpen())
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
            toolStripButton1.Text = "Open Port";
        }
    }
}
```